# How to load RAW css into Jekyll?

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/my_file.css">
```

on a simple index page

And this .css file is on `_assets/css/my_file.css`

But it won't be loaded when I load my page. If I try `localhost:4000/assets/css/my_file.css` I go to a 404 page.

Answer (score 1):

in jekyll check `baseurl` in  _config.yml

```
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
```

for local development use just empty string like above, then import css like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/style.css">
```

for images:

```
<img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/img/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="logo"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create the `assets/css` folders in your root directory and save `my_file.css` in there.

Now it will show in your generated `_site` folder and is available at `http://localhost:4000/assets/css/my_file.css`

To include it in your header use

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/css/my_file.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">`

and you are good to go.